# How to know which checkbox is selected?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have multiple 'yes' 'no' checkbox on VF page and I am trying to display text field when 'Yes' checkbox is clicked but not in all case.
I need to display text field for some of the checkbox. How to make use of this code and identify which checkbox is selected and based
on that I can display the textbox.

```
 <apex:pageblocksection >
        <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!chkBx}" label="Yes"> 
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePanel" action="{!click}"/>    
        </apex:inputcheckbox> 
       <apex:inputCheckbox label="No"/>  
</apex:pageblocksection>

<apex:pageblocksection >
   <apex:outputPanel id="thePanel"> 
           <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!displayInputputText}">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Input Text" />
                <apex:inputText value="{!input}"/>  
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageblocksection>
```

Controller:

```
public class CheckboxController{
    public Boolean displayInputputText{get;set;}
    public Boolean chkBx{get;set;}
    public String input{get;set;}       
    public PageReference click(){    
         if(chkBx){
             displayInputputText = true;
         }
         else{
             displayInputputText = false;
         }
         return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to do it in controller of on page? In controller just write `if (chkBx == true) {yourLogicHere}`

Comment: In controller or VF page but chkbx==true not working..

Comment: post your code snippet where you did try to use `chkbx==true`

Comment: Only displaying for one checkbox lebel, I want to make use of same code for all other checkbox.

Comment: @avidForce are you using `value="{!chkBx}"` for all checkboxes?

Comment: Yes, I am using value="{!chBx}"

Comment: It appears to me that you need to use something more like a select list. The code you have now will execute everytime any checkbox is clicked. That won't allow you to keep track of which boxes in your list are "selected".